# Order history access item/cart totals in payment currency

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce2, currency

I'm a bit confused at how to show previous orders taken in another currency. For example, if I take a payment in EUR but my default currency is GBP the order price (eg subtotal, tax, total, etc) are stored and later retrieved in GBP. If i want to show the amount taken based on the currency used at payment - ie. EUR - I know I can access `paymentcurrency` from the cart/order object for that currency.

However, I want to convert these based on the conversion rate that was in the CMS at the point of the transaction (which is liable to change at a later date). Is there a way to access the order and item totals for an order in the currency that the item was paid with using the currency conversion rate from when the order was placed?

Sorry if this is straightforward but finding it hard form the documentation and sample templates to work this out.